# QProcess fails to pass the arguments

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qprocess

I want to make a small Qt application to be able to switch between steam accounts quicky using -login login passsword as a launch options. The problem is that I can't run steam.exe from using my Qt app with needed arguments. 
Here is a code:

```
QString path("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam");
QStringList arg;
arg << "-launch 123 123";
QString item = arg.takeAt(0);
QString res("Steam.exe");
QString program = "\"" + path + "/" + res + "\"";
QProcess* process = new QProcess();
process->startDetached(program, arg);
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 problems with the code in your question:

1. `QString item = arg.takeAt(0);` Here
   [`takeAt(0)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#takeAt) removes your argument from the `arg`-list. So the moment you pass `arg` to `startDetached` it is already empty.
2. You'll need to use `-login` instead of `-launch` as command line argument. See [Steam support documentation](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5623-QOSV-5250).
3. You'll have to pass username and password as separate arguments, so `QStringList arg = QStringList() << "-login" << "123" << "123";` instead of `QStringList arg; arg << "-launch 123 123";`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me was:

```
QStringList arg;
    arg << "-login";
    arg << "123";
    arg << "123";
```

instead of:

```
arg << "-launch 123 123";
```